# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost

i downloaded mongoDB and it works just fine but when i want to use REST API and use `npm run dev` in command line it gave me this error..
[That's an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR8Rn.jpg)

```
(node:10100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\Node Js\task-manager\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:800:32)
    at D:\Node Js\task-manager\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:10
    at D:\Node Js\task-manager\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (D:\Node Js\task-manager\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\Node Js\task-manager\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:340:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node Js\task-manager\src\db\mongoose.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Node Js\task-manager\src\index.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
(node:10100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10100) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

and before that when i wanted to connect database and project it work but now its not work and when i try to connect it is stopping
[And thats not connecting picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBEZu.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your URL is not properly formatted,

use below URL

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/{DATABASE_NAME}
```

Comment: Im not using URL i downloaded mongoDB

Comment: you need a URL to connect to any database it is called as a connection string, In case of DB is downloaded locally it will be localhost URL (I gave localhost URL itself),  just update in code where you have  127.0.0.1:27017 (I got this from 1st line of your error)

Answer (score 5):

Take in account that MongoDB should be running before issuing `npm run dev`.

You have to initialize database engine with [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/) command first.
Sometimes it's easy to forget this step.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch, I changed the comment redaction. Sorry if it looked like a question.

Comment: I disregard, but re-edited anyway. Hope it looks clearer for everybody now. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Now it cannot be confused for a question anymore.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when I changed "mongodb://`localhost`:27017" to "mongodb://`127.0.0.1`:27017", it worked

Answer (score 0):

At first start your MongoDB on your local machine and connect it using `localhost:27017`.
Also don't forget to use URL `mongodb://localhost:27017/{DATABASE_NAME}` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install and run the MongoDB server on your machine.

Then try the below code in your program

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp', {
useNewUrlParser: true
});

To check MongoDB service, you can follow in Task Manager service or running "mongo" command in Command Prompt.

[image: mongo_command]

Answer (score 0):

I am using a tutorial on using the mongoDb, and I came accross this error. I am using Windows environments, so i just reinstalled my mongo community server. before i was just having the mongoDb compass without any server installed that would listening. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for future searchers, i was using docker-compose and i got this error.
I was passing the user and the password by environment variables, and forgot to replicate it into docker-compose, so my variables were returning `undefined`.

If you got this error, you should verify if you're passing the variables into your `.yml` file to nodejs container.

i.e.:

```
node:
    image: "node:16.3.0"
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
      - PORT=${PORT}
      - MONGO_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check whether `mongod` is running on default port of 27017.
2. Run `mongod` locally before running the `mongoose code`
3. For setting up mongo and mongod default on bash shell on windows follow given steps :

   - `cd ~`
   - `touch .bash_profile`
   - `vim .bash_profile`
   - Go into insert mode on vim and edit the file as follows

     - `alias mongod="/c/Program\ Files/mongodb-5.0.5/bin/mongod.exe"`
     - `alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/mongodb-5.0.5/bin/mongo.exe"`
   - Enter `esc` and type `:wq` and press enter
   - Now you can access `mongo` and `mongod` on shell using their names

Answer (score -1):

For Windows, Just repair from MongoDBCommunity Edition MSI Installer and connect via Compass or your Node JS application. Files might have gone corrupt.

Comment: How do we do the repair?